# Sitecore MVC Field Update Programmatically

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, sitecore7

How can I change field value by using MVC?

I have a form in view like this and defined Controll Name and Action in ViewRendering Item.

```razor
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Components", "testController")

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeList, new List<SelectListItem> 
        { 
            new SelectListItem{Text="Enable", Value="True", Selected = (isSet ? true : false)},
            new SelectListItem{Text="Disable", Value="False", Selected = (!isSet ? true : false)}
        })

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

What I want to do is when "submit" clicked, controller gets the form data and update field value in Sitecore in EditorMode.

How Can I do??

In Controller, this is what I'm thinking:

```razor
public class Components: SitecoreController
{
    public ActionResult testController()
    {
        if (submit clicks) {
            ComponentModel ob = new ComponentModel();
            ob.Initialize(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering);

            string selectedValue = selectedValue from View;

            ob.item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            using(new EditContext())
            {
                ob.CheckBoxField.Checked = (selectedValue == "True" ? true : false);
            }
            ob.item.Editing.EndEdit();
            return PartialView(ob);
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by in editor mode? Do you mean to make this code work in page editor? Sorry, the problem is not clear from the question

Comment: Yes. the code is working when it is page editor mode. But, it is not the main issue. I can easily add the condition like "Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved and I got exactly what I want to do by using Controller Rendering with Ajax.

I used DropList instead of Checkbox for checkbox field type.

**Model**

```razor
public class ComponentModel : IRenderingModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Item PageItem { get; set; }
    public Sitecore.Data.Fields.CheckboxField chBox { get; set; }
    ... some other declared data types based on templates if you want ...

    public void Initialize(Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering rendering)
    {
        Rendering = rendering;
        Item = rendering.Item;
        PageItem = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.Current.Item;

        Title = FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Title");
        ... more if you want ...
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```razor
public class Components : Controller
{
    //
    // POST: /Components/

    public ActionResult ComponentView(string changedValue, string fieldName)
    {

        ComponentModel ss = new ComponentModel();
        ss.Initialize(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering);
        Item item = ss.Item;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(changedValue) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldName))
        {
            ss.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                switch (fieldName)
                {
                    ... conditions ...
                }
            }
            ss.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
        return PartialView(ss);
    }
}
```

**View**

```razor
@model yournamespace.ComponentModel
@using Sitecore.Mvc

@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
{  
    if (!@Sitecore.Data.ID.IsID(Model.Rendering.DataSource))
    {
        <div>No Associated Datasource.<br />Please Create New Datasource</div><br />
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="newdata">
            <h3>This is page editor</h3>
            Title: @Html.Raw(Model.Title) <br />

            DropList: <select name="list" id="fieldName" onclick="javascript:dlOnChangeUpdate('fieldName');">
                <option value="True" @Html.Raw((Model.chBox.Checked) ? "selected" : "")>Enable</option>
                <option value="False" @Html.Raw((!Model.chBox.Checked) ? "selected" : "")>Disable</option>
            </select><br />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function dlOnChangeUpdate(fieldName)
                {
                    $("#" + fieldName).on('change', function () {
                        var changedValue = $("#" + fieldName).val();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ComponentModel","Components")',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { "changedValue": changedValue, "fieldName": fieldName },
                            context: this,
                            success: function (data) {
                                Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest('webedit:save()');
                                console.log("success", data);
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert('error: ' + data);
                                console.log("error", data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <div id="info">
        <h3>This is preview</h3>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in SecurityDisabler instead. Pseudo code:

```razor
public ActionResult testController()
{
    if (submit clicks) {
        ComponentModel ob = new ComponentModel();
        ob.Initialize(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering);

        string selectedValue = selectedValue from View;
        using(new SecurityDisabler()){
            var item = Sitecore.Data.Databases.GetDatabase("master");
            item.Editing.BeginEdit();

            item.Fields["CheckBoxField"].Value = (selectedValue == "True" ? true : false);
            item.Editing.EndEdit();
            item.SaveChanges();
        }
        return PartialView(ob);
    }

    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but it is not the main issue. What I want to know is the part of "if (submit click)"